# Websocket Client to Server sending a Float32Array - what am I doing wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, websocket

I am sending a typed Float32Array to a node [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) server and the values I get are very different from the ones I send. With the same exact data, while using a Uint8Array everything is fine.

Client boils down to something like this:

```
client.connection.send(new Float32Array([1.5,3.14]).buffer);
```

And on the server side:

```
var data = new FloatArray32(msg); // data is 

{ 
 '0': 0,
 '1': 0,
 '2': 192,
 '3': 63,
 '4': 195,
 '5': 245,
 '6': 72,
 '7': 64
}
```

If I change the type of the array that I am sending to `Uint8Array`, the received data is

```
{'0': 1, '1': 3 }
```

which is normal(I think?) for the given type.

So, am I doing something totally wrong, or is this a bug with the ws module?

Comment: Generally websockets only accept strings, but some browsers accept blobs now as well. I do not believe they accept arrays and objects, so the array is probably stringified and parsed back, and somewhere during that the data changes. Try stringifying yourself and send a string, and see what you get.

Comment: `FloatArray32` is a typo right?

Comment: This is infact not true, WebSockets accept ArrayBuffer objects, also you can make the connection be binary by setting this property of the WebSocket object: onnection.binaryType = "arraybuffer"; where connection is the WebSocket object. The WebSocket frames are binary as per the WebSocket protocol https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5

Comment: @mscdex Float32Array, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data looks right to me. It's two 32-bit floats in little endian format.

To verify:

```
var buf = new Buffer([0,0,192,63,195,245,72,64]);
console.log(buf.readFloatLE(0));
// outputs: 1.5
console.log(buf.readFloatLE(4));
// outputs: 3.140000104904175
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to go directly back to a `Float32Array` from a `Buffer`, but you could do something like this if you need to do that:

```
var fa = new Float32Array(buf.length / 4);
for (var i = 0, p = 0; i < buf.length; i += 4, ++p)
  fa[p] = buf.readFloatLE(i);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I was assuming that working with raw array data was the same in Node, as it would be in a browser. I ended up using Float64Array(double) for my messages.