# Websocket & Javascript & Float32Array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to send some binary data between a NodeJS client and NodeJS server via a Websocket connection.
This data is updated every 3 seconds and consists of two float values.

I construct the payload as such inside a function:

```js
for( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
var globalMsec = Date.now() / 1000.0
var outBuff = new Float32Array(6)

outBuff[0] = 1.0

outBuff[1] = 123456789
outBuff[2] = globalMsec
outBuff[3] = -5.0

//rapid wind dat
outBuff[4] = Math.random() * 10
outBuff[5] = Math.random() * 360
        
console.log("globalMsec = "+globalMsec)
console.log("[2] = "+outBuff[2]+" ==== "+"[4] = "+outBuff[4]+" [5] " +"rnd2 = "+outBuff[5])
}
```

This works well, with one exception. If I console.log the value of globalMsec, I get it incrementing as expected (going up by 3 seconds each iteration).

However, if I check the contents of outBuff[2] right after setting it, the value does not match globalMsec. Usually, it is a higher number than globalMsec... and only changes every minute or so.

I do verify that outBuff[4] and outBuff[5] are both changing with each interation, as expected.

Anyone have any ideas why?

I tried deleting just outBuff[2] as well... still does not work.

Comment: Usage of delete keyword is wrong; delete keyword deletes a property of an object. Could you try `delete outBuff[2];` and see if it works?

Comment: @SamGrant That's just adding a loop and some `console.log` output; it does not demonstrate the "*I check the contents of outBuff[2] right before sending it out, the value does not match globalMsec*" part. What output are you getting and what would you have expected instead?

Comment: @Bergi, the example demonstrates the issue. I am expecting that outBuff[2] will change to match the 'real' value stored in globalMsec.
This fiddle has the logging of globalMsec as well. You can see that the value that is place in the Array does NOT match the original value.  Run the fiddle and check the console output.  https://jsfiddle.net/gtq1e769/2/

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017812/websocket-client-to-server-sending-a-float32array-what-am-i-doing-wrong

Comment: @DickensAS, thanks. Following the comment to the answer there, Changing to a Float64Array fixes the issue. The question here is "why"?

Comment: @SamGrant Well it's rounded to float32 (ie. 24 bits / ~9 decimal digits of precision), but it's not a different value. If you want to store the full `globalMsec` value (with all 64 bits of the js number), then you need a `Float64Array`